# Paypal sandbox cant login to sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im trying to login to my Paypal sandbox account by navigating to

```
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts
```

and then clicking the "enter sandbox site"

For some reason im being redirected to

```
https://merchant.paypal.com/
```

and i cannot login to my sandbox account,

Comment: it works as intended, are you able to reproduce?

Comment: Well i don't know what you mean by "it works as intended" as i cannot login to the sandbox account. I'm doing exactly the stages as i noted above and I'm getting to paypal's production environment and not the sandbox

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior in my own developer account. Have you tried a different browser or clearing your cookies and java cache?

Comment: Here is the direct link to [PayPal Sandbox](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home). I tested the sandbox.paypal.com and was redirected as expected to the correct PayPal Sandbox site.